# csv to pandas dataframe contains semicolon

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to upload a csv file as a pandas dataframe that I obtained from a public database. When I upload the csv with pd.read_csv function I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 40: invalid start byte
```

For which I added the encoding argument in the read_csv function as:

```
df= pd.read_csv('Species_Dataframe.csv', encoding = "latin1")
```

and get the following output:

```
    Species;Protein_ID;Optimal growth Temp [°C];Melting point [°C]
0   S.cerevisiae;A0A023PXQ4;30;52.403
1   C.elegans;A0A023T4K3;20;37.963
2   M.musculus;A0A023T778;37;54.933
3   C.elegans;A0A061ACF5;20;49.459
4   C.elegans;A0A061ACH4;20;42.59
```

The original dataframe is as such:

```
Species         Protein ID               growth temperature [°C]    Melting point [°C] 
S.cerevisiae    A0A023PXQ4_YMR173W-A          30                       52,403
C.elegans       A0A023T4K3_                   20                       37,963
M.musculus      A0A023T778_Magohb             37                       54,933
C.elegans       A0A061ACF5_fbl-1              20                       49,459
```

Not sure why the semi-colons are also present. I've tried modifying the original file various times to avoid this but always come to the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the separator:

```
df= pd.read_csv('Species_Dataframe.csv', encoding = "latin1", sep=";")
```

Comment: This was the correct way, I feel quite silly because it was due to my regional setting of Office. https://www.answertabs.com/is-csv-excel-file-comma-or-semicolon-separated-delimited/ I will accept the answer once I can :)